# JIRA issue macro configuration

Tags: jira, confluence

I am trying to add new fields to the quick Jira issue creation, the one where you select the text and then can create the issue.

When you select Epic as the type it will show up a field called Epic Name but I wanted to configure another field to show up, like the Blocks field.

Was anyone able to do this?

Thanks

Comment: if you can add example it would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Jira can be configured to do exactly this, please have a look at the [Associating field behavior with issue types](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/associating-field-behavior-with-issue-types-802592562.html) documentation.